# Run SQL package with different parameters at different times of the day

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, jobs, schedule

I am trying to run an SQL package from our SQL Server via a scheduled job at different times of the day with different parameters. The package imports property specific information (our company has multiple properties) that is available after a certain time of the day. The package accepts a property code parameter to identify the property information to be imported.

If possible, I would like to re-use one package/job and set up multiple steps that execute at certain times of the day.

Is there a better way to set this up besides using multiple jobs that run the same package with its own parameters?

I would really appreciate some advice, thank you.

Comment: I am confused why these are JOBs, why aren't you just using a stored procedure. If it is because you want them to run on a schedule, then who provides the different parameters and how? Walk us through a use/best case senerio.

Comment: The property code parameter is "hard-coded" and does not change, neither does the time the package should run (**per property/package**). However, all packages accept the current date/time of the SQL server as parameter. Per your suggestion: how is running a stored procedure on a schedule different than running a package on a schedule?

Comment: You were not clear about the what the "parameter" was. If it is the date, your can use GETDATE() as a parameter which gives you the current date/time. It sounded like it was a parameter that you have to supply everytime, so my question is why is it on a schedule if you have to manually supply a parameter. I know better now. [Using a date as parameter](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1645313-how-pass-parameter-values-sql-job-schedule.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using GETDATE() as one of the parameters. However, my question was whether or not it is a good practice to have 20 jobs set up with their own schedule, instead of 1 job with 20 steps where each step has its own scheduled time to run.

Comment: That was your question? I missed that, sorry. Multple steps allow you to stop execution if a step fails so the thing you do in step 10, will NOT run if step 9 fails. If you care about that requirement, use a sinlge job with multiple steps. If you dont, use multiple jobs.  If you need to control the time of each step, then you must use multiple jobs.  Really, the answer is based on what you need to accomplish.

Comment: I need to control the time a step runs. I was hoping that a step could run at a certain time. Thank you for the clarification. Please answer that and I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple steps allow you to stop execution if a step fails so the thing you do in step 10, will NOT run if step 9 fails.

If you care about that requirement, use a single job with multiple steps. If you don’t, use multiple jobs.

If you need to control the time of each step, then you must use multiple jobs.

Really, the answer is based on what you need to accomplish.

Comment: BTW, you could do a step the will wait for a specified amount of time, but I dont think you want to do that, based on your requirements.

Comment: I ended up building a package schedule table and a watcher. Thank you!